# Slick Util Texture Get RGB Value for Pixel

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm currently messing around with Slick-Util (not Slick) for game development. I'm trying to get the RGBA value of a pixel in a Texture object, but can't see any way to. I know that I can get them by loading them through a BufferedImage but I want to see if there's a built-in way that doesn't require me to take up extra space/create a Texture wrapper or something.

Any ideas if this exists or not?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Texture.getTextureData() was what I was looking for. I'd seen it before but hadn't figured out how it worked. It essentially returns an array of bytes that goes [r0, g0, b0, a0, r1, g1, b1, a1, etc...]. Here's my full "helper" implementation: http://pastebin.com/xcyZzDEF